# jquery div undefined with .html()

Tags: html, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4

I am using Jquery ajax.

I have made ajax call to fetch data and concact the html string and attached to id of div.

```
$("#divMenuList").html(JsMenuListHtml);

alert($("#divMenuList").html());
```

But with alert is showing undefined. I have it using listing if i am page change it showing first time with html string but if i will delete second page record and re-call that function it will showing undefined.

Here is the whole function:

```
function performlisting(data, JsCurrPage) {
    var JsMenuTitle = '';
    var JsOrderNumber = '';    
    var JsMenuId = '';    
    var JsMenuListHtml = '';    
    var JsCounter = 0;    
    var JsAlternateRow = '';    
    var JsIsActive = "false";    
    var JsIsActiveClass = "";    
    var JsIsActiveTitle = "";


    if (data.Data.length > 0) {
        for (i = 0; i < data.Data.length ; i++) {
            JsCounter++;

            if (JsCounter % 2 == 0) {
                JsAlternateRow = "alternate-row";
            }
            else {
                JsAlternateRow = '';
            }

            //set true/false for update status
            if (data.Data[i]['IsActive'] == true) {
                JsIsActive = "false";
                JsIsActiveClass = "icon-3 info-tooltip";
                JsIsActiveTitle = "Published";
            }
            else if (data.Data[i]['IsActive'] == false) {
                JsIsActive = "true";
                JsIsActiveClass = "icon-4 info-tooltip";
                JsIsActiveTitle = "UnPublished";
            }
            else {
                JsIsActive = "false";
                JsIsActiveClass = "icon-4 info-tooltip";
                JsIsActiveTitle = "UnPublished";
            }

            JsMenuTitle = data.Data[i]['MenuTitle'];
            JsOrderNumber = data.Data[i]['OrderNumber'];
            JsMenuId = data.Data[i]['MenuId'];

            JsMenuListHtml = JsMenuListHtml +
                '<tr class= ' + JsAlternateRow + '>' +
                    '<td style="width:3.4%;"><input type="checkbox" value=' + JsMenuId + ' /></td><td  style="width:38.8%;">' + JsMenuTitle + '</td>' +
                    '<td style="width:39%;">' +
                    '<a title="Up-Rank" href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return performUpMenu(\'' + JsOrderNumber + '\', \'' + JsMenuId + '\')"><img  src=' + JsUpImage + '></a>' +
                    '<a title="Down-Rank"  href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return performDownMenu(\'' + JsOrderNumber + '\', \'' + JsMenuId + '\')"><img  src=' + JsDownImage + '></a>' +
                    '' + JsOrderNumber + '</td>' +

                    '<td class="options-width"><a href="/Admin/Menu/AddEdit/' + JsMenuId + '/'+JsCurrPage+'" title="Edit Menu" class="icon-1 info-tooltip"></a>' +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);" onclick="return performdeletemenu(\'' + JsMenuId + '\');" title="Delete Menu" class="icon-2 info-tooltip"></a>' +
                    '<a href="javascript:void(0);"   onclick="return performstatusmenu(\'' + JsIsActive + '\', \'' + JsMenuId + '\');" title= ' + JsIsActiveTitle + ' class=' + JsIsActiveClass + '></a>' +
                    '</td>' +
                '</tr>';
        }

        $("#divMenuList").html("");
        $("#divMenuList").html(JsMenuListHtml);

        alert($("#divMenuList").html());
        //hide num of raws dropdown
        if (parseInt(JsTotalRecs) > parseInt(JsPageSize)) {
            alert("Called1");
            SetPaging(JsTotalRecs, parseInt(JsCurrPage));
        }
        else {
            alert("Called");
            $("#pager").html('');             
        }

        $("#CurrPage").val(JsCurrPage);
        SetAllCheckboxes();
    }
    else {            
        if ($("#CurrPage").val() > 1) {
            //Error Message Pager
            $("#product-table").html("");
            $("#divSuccessMessage").html("");
            alert(parseInt($("#CurrPage").val()));
            GetListing(parseInt($("#CurrPage").val() - 1), parseInt(JsPageSize));
        }
        else {
            $("#product-table").html("");
            $("#divErrMessage").html("");
            $("#divSuccessMessage").html("");
        }            
    }
}
```

Regards

Comment: Can you please show the full AJAX code, so we can see at what point you're getting the `html()` value.

Comment: Remember: with AJAX, _below_ doesn't mean _after_.

Comment: Function added to my post, issue is not first time ajax call, but when i am doing this flow -> listing -> paging -> click on second page -> on second page 1 record -> delete that record -> and calling posted function then it is showing undefined, normal page changing it is showing fetched data.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan : Did you get flow, other wise i am explaining you in brief, During listing it is not alerting undfined, it is showing data with alert, but as i have mentioned flow then showing undefined.

Comment: I think that a jsFiddle will help more than the currently available code. If you post code, try to narrow it down to the relevant sections, but don't leave out relevant pieces. Where is the ajax call?. If you can create a jsFiddle with your data, that would be great (you can use JSON.stringify() to get it as a string). And avoid `alert()` for debugging purposes, use the console (`console.log()`).